# How can I show the DID or Hunt Group on a Mitel 5320e phone?

Tags: voip, mitel

We have a Mitel 5000 running a building full of 5320e desk phones with PRI from a T1. I recently started setting up custom DIDs for certain projects, but have not yet found a way to let the person receiving the call know what sort of call they are receiving.

I would like to display either the name of the hunt group or the DID the call came in on so they can answer the phone appropriately. The closest I've found so far is assigning one of the soft keys on the left to Hunt Group, but that seems to be for letting a user call a hunt group. Has anyone else found a decent way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Someone over at Spiceworks pointed me in the right direction. In the Mitel DB Programming tool, find each phone that needs this functionality and edit their Flags thusly:

```
CO/IC Reseize = YES
Expanded CO Call Information On Displays = YES
Outside Party Call Information has Priority = NO
```

This gets us the name assigned to the inbound DID shown at the top of the screen, and the Caller ID info on the last line (where before we had CID in both places).